# Remove "tech. rep." from all bib entries automatically via code in main latex file

Tags: bibliographies

I use OverLeaf and have it connected to my Mendeley account. Mendeley outputs the bib file and syncs with OverLeaf whenever I add new papers to my Mendeley library. Technical reports have "Tech. Rep." on the bibliography which I do not like at all.

I have seen other StackExchange posts where people recommend simply deleting "Technical Report" from the type section in the bib file. This works, however, every time Mendeley and OverLeaf sync, all bib entries need to be tweaked again since Mendeley outputs the type as "technical report" every time.

Is there a code that could be added to my main manuscript latex file which searches through my .bib file for all @techreport entries? Ideally, I could control what is output for "type" for technical reports specifically and it would save so much time in the future as I keep adding tech reports to my library. At the moment, I think I would want it empty {} but I might want it to be {Technical Report}.

The solution has to be biblatex free please!

Thanks in advance!

````
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{unicode=true}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}

@TechReport{Smith2018,
  author      = {Smith, Joanne},
  title       = {The Impact of Maths},
  institution = {},
  year        = {2018},
  type        = {Technical Report},
  number      = {},
  address     = {},
  }

@TechReport{Smith2019,
  author      = {Smith, Joanne},
  title       = {The Impact of Physics},
  institution = {},
  year        = {2019},
  type        = {Technical Report},
  number      = {},
  address     = {},
  }

@TechReport{Smith2020,
  author      = {Smith, Joanne},
  title       = {The Impact of Chemistry},
  institution = {},
  year        = {2020},
  type        = {Technical Report},
  number      = {},
  address     = {},
  }

@TechReport{Smith201,
  author      = {Smith, Joanne},
  title       = {The Impact of Biology},
  institution = {},
  year        = {2021},
  type        = {Technical Report},
  number      = {},
  address     = {},
  }

\end{filecontents}```
````

Comment: Why are you using the entry type `@TechReport` for papers that would not appear to belong in this category in the first place? Why not use either `@misc` or `@unpublished`?

Comment: Could you advance your example into a MWE which can be compiled?

Comment: Btw, why is `biblatex` not an option?

Comment: @lukeflo - The OP's real issue can't be fixed anyway by switching to biblatex...